# How to sort bookmarks by date in Chrome web browser

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

Chrome is somehow missing one of the most basic features you would expect on a web browser: sorting bookmarks by date.  Is there any way around this issue besides not using Chrome?  I love Chrome but I have thousands of bookmarks.

Comment: Did you check the Chrome Web Store? Someone may have already created an extension to do this.

Comment: I found a couple of bookmark-sorting extensions in there (searching with "sort bookmarks"), but they both seem to sort by name only. You could try persuading the developers of those extensions to add a date-sorting option; they may not realize there's a demand for that ability.

Comment: Pretty ridiculous how Chrome wouldn't have this feature built in, and the solution is a _desktop_ application. People didn't even make Extensions for this.

Comment: Hah!  I'm sure this is a conscious decision. For years I've been amazed at how Chrome, despite all it's greatness, is pretty useless in terms of managing bookmarks. I figured the message they send is clear, and a bit sad, but basically it's:  _bookmarks are messy, use search instead. Oh and don't use offline search, use Google_ ;-)    So in essence, I think we have to use something else to manage a "sane" bookmarks library than Chrome. Perhaps an extension or some web app, I dunno yet.

Answer (score 11):

Chrome Bookmark Manager does allow users to sort bookmarks by name, but it only allows you to do this for one folder at a time.

[Chrome Bookmarks Sorter](http://jamesburgess.co.uk/blog/wp-content/plugins/download-monitor/download.php?id=2) is a handy tool (for Windows) which will allow users to sort bookmarks recursively by name or date added through all of your bookmark folders.

[image]

To recursively sort bookmarks in Google Chrome, close all Google Chrome windows and launch this application, select the parameters you want to sort the bookmarks as, and click on the Sort Bookmarks button.

The utility will take care of reordering the bookmarks as you have chosen. Chrome Bookmarks Sorter is a portable software.

[Source](http://techie-buzz.com/softwares/google-chrome-bookmarks-sorter.html)

Comment: I was just writing about this one as well. How portable is it, though? The author says that .NET Framework 3.5 is required, which I think does not support anything other than MS Windows. Or maybe [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) could handle it?

Comment: @L2G portable means it doesn't need to install and the `.net framework 3.5` is very common now for most of the apps.

Comment: I downloaded this before, but now it follow dead links..

Comment: @armanke13 it seems that extension is dead for now just use this one https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/recursive-bookmark-sorter/oalceifbkhhehhinpifagdnickeeehlk?hl=en for now and check.

Comment: Sorting by name works out of the box recursively for all folders now. Tested in Chrome 63.0.3239.84.

Comment: I found the repo, download it from bitbucket https://bitbucket.org/JamesF1/chrome-bookmark-sorter/downloads/

Answer (score 10):

I found that Chrome extension [Recent Bookmarks](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/recent-bookmarks/olndffocioplakeilhkgenfgdincjlpn) works well for me on Mac and Ubuntu where the Chrome Bookmark Sorter is Windows-only.

*Update: When I got a new machine and logged into my Google account, previous Chrome bookmark order was no longer correctly preserved.  Still the best alternative I've found for non-Windows, but not perfect.*

Comment: Best solution without having to download an app like the top answer suggests. Limited to showing 1,000 bookmarks.

Comment: @Jason You can choose any number in the settings by editing HTML, or change directly in localStorage.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question but I came across it while googling for the same thing... then I found Dewey Bookmarks... It's exactly what chrome has been missing with the standard bookmarks manager! Their website is http://deweyapp.io/ the chrome store page is https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dewey-bookmarks/aahpfefkmihhdabllidnlipghcjgpkdm and they also have an informative github page but I don't have enough reputation to link to it.

Dewey features:

- Adding custom tags
- Generating screenshots of your bookmarks (Provided by Snapito)
- Searching and Sorting:

  - A standard search returns anything with that word in the Tag, Title or URL.
  - Add `tag:` before a word to limit results that have that specific tag applied.
  - Add `title:` before a word to limit results to titles that contain that word.
  - Add `url:` before a word to limit results to URLs that contain that word.
  - Sort your bookmarks and your search results by Date, Title, or URL.

Happy bookmarking!

Comment: I found it didn't correctly sort by date, which is what I was after.

Answer (score 3):

They also mentioned in comments a Chrome extension Sprucemarks which sorts bookmarks automatically - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fakeocdnmmmnokabaiflppclocckihoj

Comment: Doesn't sort by date-time.

Comment: @Jason it sorts.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend this chrome extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/supersorter/hjebfgojnlefhdgmomncgjglmdckngij?hl=en

It is powerful, fast and you have 10 options like Delete duplicates, Delete Empty Directories, Sort Methods, etc...

There is also this one but I had some issues with it almost every Major upgrade of CHrome so...  but the choice is yours so here the link: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/recursive-bookmark-sorter/oalceifbkhhehhinpifagdnickeeehlk

Hope this helps!

Comment: Doesn't sort by date-time.

Comment: And does not work anymore with the current version (60.0.3112.113)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this extension [Booklyst](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/booklyst/jgncicmcfanpemdmknkcaahbgobahngg?hl=de&authuser=0) that sort the bookmarks by date.

Answer (score 1):

#### Sortmark

I found Sortmark which works perfect for me.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sortmark/nmhnlemdhjjebiklhbjmpkiekgjjbnfc/related

It has "Order" options:

- [Title] A-Z
- [Title] Z-A
- [URL] A-Z
- [URL] Z-A
- [Added] Old-New
- [Added] New-Old

And it can "Auto Run" to sort your exisiting bookmarks folders, or manually when you press the extension button itself.

You can specify which folders you want to sort: bar / other / mobile.

And you can specify where subfolders will be placed: top / mix / bottom

Finally there is this option to ignore the folder hierarchy in the "Bookmarks bar"

Here are pictures:

Options:

[image: Options]

Options showing "Order" dropdown

[image: Options showing "Order" dropdown]

Answer (score 0):

I exported my bookmarks on diigo.com. The site sorts automatically the bookmarks by date (what is not his first usage). Then, if you want, you can export these bookmrks from diigo to your browser and you have your bookmarks sorted by date. Sorry for my English, I'm French.

Answer (score 0):

that one worked for me like a charm .

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmark-sorter/fdhnblfnlgnfafgjcfpelkkpbhbmbgmj/related?hl=en

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1126606)

Answer (score -1):

You could try using [Recent Bookmarks 1.6.2](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/recent-bookmarks/olndffocioplakeilhkgenfgdincjlpn).

Answer (score -2):

### Alphabetize bookmarks

Taken from https://kb.nmsu.edu/page.php?id=72820

- On your computer, open Chrome.
- At the top right, click More More.
- Click Bookmarks and then Bookmark Manager.
- Browse to the folder you want to organize.
- Above your bookmarks, click Organize.
- Click Reorder by Title. Your bookmarks will be listed in alphabetical order.