# How to view all my Google Chrome bookmarks, sorted by date?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, sorting

I want to see a flat list of all my bookmarks in Google Chrome, sorted from the oldest one to the newest one.
How can I achieve this ?

Comment: When you say "flat", do you mean just URLs? Or do you want to display titles and/or dates as well? Do you want to do this once/rarely or are you looking for an extension?

Comment: By "flat" I mean, without the folders hierarchy, just a plain sequential list  of entries, each of them containing url, date and optionally title. I would like to do this often and therefore would appreciate an extension.

Comment: I  think this may be a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/464454/how-to-sort-bookmarks-by-date-in-chrome-web-browser.

Answer (score 4):

Try the Chrome [Recent Bookmarks](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/recent-bookmarks/olndffocioplakeilhkgenfgdincjlpn) extension.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, this extension only display at maximum 25 bookmarks. I would like to see all of mine.

Comment: I agree that the limitation of 25 is frustrating.  I've got your question favorited in hopes of a better solution.

Comment: Just installed and it now supports up to 1000 bookmarks. his should definitely b built-in to chrome. Sad, but at least we have extensions like this :]